# Update One Record to add object Error(NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I was playing with my nodjs and mongoDB. I found an error that I can not update a object.

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const url =
  'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.uw6pe.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
console.log(url);
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'studio';

export async function insertData(_id: string) {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('shops');

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    collection.updateOne(
      { _id: ObjectID(_id) },
      {
        $set: {
          address: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [123, 321],
          },
        },
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(res);
      },
    );
  });
}
```

I was trying to insert an address(Object), by using NestJS. And got this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5aXf.png)

So I wonder what I did wrong. I could update key : value, but I can't update key:object,
If I enter an empty object, it works.

Is there anyone who has an answare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `coordinates: [123, 321]` aren't valid coordinates, this is because `321` isn't a valid latitude value. Latitudes are between -90 and +90, whereas longitudes can be between -180 and +180.

The clue is in the error message: `"longitude/latitude out of bounds"`.

If you make sure that your coordinates valid you shouldn't run into this error.

Useful docs for reading:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_syste

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand that part.